# User does not have permission to access List on Communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, communication-site

My scenario : I have a SharePoint group that have contribute permission on the site, there is a list that by default inherit from the site permission to eventually give access to the group, when I use my test user found in that same group I get the error: "Access denied". You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."

The site is a communication site on SharePoint Online. No lookup column are used in the list. I even tried to break the permission and assign unique permission to the site but it didn't work. Note that the user account are synced to azure ad from on premise servers if it helps.

I tried with a new blank list, the error persists.

Can you help please?

Comment: What are attempting to do with the test user when you get the access denied error?

Comment: @CallumCrowley just trying to access the list

Comment: @CallumCrowley I tried with a new blank list, the error persists.

Comment: Is the group a Microsoft 365 group or a security group?

Comment: @CallumCrowley group created directly on sharepoint

Comment: Can you go to the site permissions for the site and use the check permissions button to check the permissions for your test user?

Comment: @CallumCrowley its contribute given directly

Comment: Found out that the default contribute permission was modified hence causing the access denied. I have reset all the default permission and it works fine now

Comment: Surprised that the default permission level had been changed. I would definitely not change default permission levels.